# Перенос текста с одной TextView на другую

Tags: java, android, textview

Имеется две TextView и довольной большой текст, не помещающийся целиком на одну TextView. Каким образом можно сделать перенос не помещающегося текста на другую вьюху?

Comment: а может вам сделать TextView скроллящимся? 
http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/10/how-to-make-scrollable-textview-in-android.html

Comment: @YungBlade, в моём случае это не выход